# Cache specific network storage directories locally

Tags: ssd, network-shares, nas, cache

I need a solution that would allow me to pick certain directories on network storage (NAS) to be cached locally on my SSD. How I imagine that would work is similar to Google Drive Filestream, I could see, use and edit all files available on the network drive, however I could pick a specific directory or file to be cached locally. I'd like to then see some visual representation (like green check mark) indicating that directory is cached locally, if I (or any program on my PC) would request that file, it would actually be loaded from my local storage, rather trough LAN. That directory would be kept in sync with the NAS. When I no longer needed high speed access to that directory, I could de-cache it.

To better describe my use case, I need it for video editing. NAS would provide superior capacity, drive redundancy with RAID and ability for multiple team members to collaborate. Directories with projects that are actively being worked on would be cached locally to allow for high capacity I/O (video editing is very I/O demanding in editing phase) and kept in sync with the NAS.

Any ideas how to solve this, ideally natively in Windows? Other ways are of course welcome as well.

Thank you!

Comment: First, as this is written, it is asking us to recommend a product. We do not entertain requests product recommendations on SuperUser because products are prone to change and subject to a large amount of personal opinion in their use. Second, Windows has Offline Files that works with any networked files.

Comment: @music2myear Good point, I edited the question. As to the windows natively supporting this, care to share more details?

Comment: Look in the Control Panel for Sync Center, or right-click on any network folder and select Make Available Offline.

Comment: Oh, great tip! Looks like the kind of thing I need! :-) Is there a way to specify what internal drive should be used for caching?

Comment: Please add that location change request to the original question and see my answer below.

Comment: This is a software recommendation, but Resilio Sync is relatively easy to setup if you can load it on your NAS.  I use it for active local syncing of what normally would be network files for specific directories and needs.  Microsoft changes window's at their own will a bit too often for me.

Answer (score 2):

Windows has included a feature called **Offline Files** for several generations.

To set it up, choose the network files or folders you wish to make available offline, right-click on them, and select **Always available offline**.

You'll manage these using the Sync Center icon in your taskbar. It's a green circle with yellow circling arrows inside it.

You can also change the default local store location of the offline cache. By default these files are stores in `C:\Windows\CSC`, but you can follow these instructions to change that:

```
From an elevated command prompt, run the following command:
REG ADD “HKLMSystemCurrentControlSetServicesCSCParameters” /v MigrationParameters /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
Run the following command as a user who is a local administrator, substituting the drive letter if necessary:
c:windowssystem32migwizmigwiz.exe
In the Windows Easy Transfer wizard, select the following options as you progress through the wizard:
a. Click Start a New Transfer.
b. Click My old computer.
c. Click Use a CD, DVD or other removable media.
d. Click External hard disk or to a network location.
e. Enter a path where you want to save Savedata.mig, and then click Next.
f. Click Advanced options.
g. On the Select user accounts, files, and settings to transfer page, do the following: 
    i. Deselect all check boxes.
    ii.Under System and program settings (all users), expand Windows Settings, expand Network and Internet, and then select the Offline Files check box.
   iii. Repeat the previous procedure for each user listed on the page.
h. Click Next to begin the transfer process.
In the registry, create a string value called CacheLocation under HKLMSystemCurrentControlSetServicesCSCParameters. To this value, assign the NT format name of the new folder where you want the cache to be. For example, if you want the cache to be in d:csc, type ??d:csc.
Create d:csc (or whatever path you used in the previous step).
Restart the computer.
Run c:windowssystem32migwizmigwiz.exe and select the following options as you progress through the wizard:
a. Click Continue a transfer in progress.
b. Click No, I’ve copied files and settings to a CD, DVD, or other removable media.
c. Click On an external hard disk or network location.
d. Enter the path to the .mig file created in Step 3e.
e. Map the user account on the old computer to the corresponding one on the new computer.
f. Click Next, and then click Transfer. 
Log off, log on, and then make sure you can correctly access your offline files.
```

*From here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2006/12/12/moving-the-offline-files-cache-in-windows-vista/*